# Around formatting won't work with a imaginary number and small error

Tags: output-formatting, around

The new function of Mathematica 12, `Around`, is a replacement of the obsolete `ErrorBar` function from `ErrorBarPlots` package. It's a nice function, but I found out that if the center value is imaginary and the error is too small, the default styling showing a plus-minus sign would fail.

For example,

```
Around[1.500 , 3.*10^-6]
```

gives
$$1.5000000\pm30$$

```
Around[1.500 I, 3.*10^-5]
```

gives
$$0.000000+1.500000 \,i\pm0.000030$$
but

```
Around[1.500 I, 3.*10^-6]
```

gives

> Around[0. + 1.5 I, 3.*10^-6]

This certainly won't affect calculation, but it's still a problem. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I think you're missing an `I` or two, yes?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I apologize, you're right, I missed two `I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be a bug, but there's a threshold you can use as a workaround:

```
Language`UncertaintyDump`$redThreshold
(*  0.00001  *)
```

The threshold must be set at the time the boxes are created.

Temporary setting means creating the cell programmatically:

```
Block[{Language`UncertaintyDump`$redThreshold = 10^-8},
 CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Around[1.500 I, 3.*10^-6], "Output"]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use a persistent setting and normal output will use the new value:

```
Language`UncertaintyDump`$redThreshold = 10.^-6;
Around[1.500 I, 3.*10^-6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there any side effect changing this threshold value might bring?

Comment: @Turgon It will change when `Around` is displayed in the `"AroundSeq"` style instead of the `"Around"` style. Examples. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gxX25.png . Aside from that I don't know.  It seems unlikely that a threshold would be used for two purposes. In the use here, it switches between the internal functions `redpmStructure[]` and `pmStructure[]`, which create the two formatted output styles. But as it is undocumented, I cannot be sure it does not have other side effects. (To me it seems unlikely that it does, FWIW.)